# WP galleries in posts after import. How do I do it?

Tags: plugins, posts, images, gallery

I moved the website posts with Wp All Export and All import, which worked fine, but many of the posts contained galleries (Wordpresses gallery with [gallery] shortcode). The problem is that now the galleries do not appear. When editing a post, the shortcode shows the IDs, which have been updated OK, they match the images on the new website, yet nothing appears and it says no images to display.
I use a Divi theme, if that matters.

Any ideas? It is very urgent!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.